# Get bash DEBUG trap to execute only once for and/or lists?

Tags: bash, prompt, trap

Suppose I set a trap on `DEBUG` like so:

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND # don't want $PROMPT_COMMAND triggering DEBUG trap
trap 'printf %s\\n "most recent history line: $(history 1)" >&2' DEBUG
```

If I do a simple command, then it prints my command to stderr:

```
$ echo foo
most recent history line:   483  echo foo
```

However, if I run an and/or list, the `DEBUG` trap is invoked multiple times, once per list command executed:

```
$ echo foo && echo bar
most recent history line:   483  echo foo && echo bar
foo
most recent history line:   483  echo foo && echo bar
bar
```

Is there a way I can get the `DEBUG` trap to execute only once per command (simple or otherwise) entered at the prompt?  If not, what is the best way for my trap code to detect whether it has already executed since the last time the prompt was drawn?

Comment: Sounds like you want the equivalent of `zsh`'s `preexec()` hook.

Comment: See [this](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas:  Thanks for the link.  It looks like `preexec.bash` basically does what I do in my answer (via the `preexec_interactive_mode` variable), so maybe the approach in my answer is as non-kludgy as it can get.  I do wish bash had something like zsh's `preexec()` hook.

Comment: See also https://jichu4n.com/posts/debug-trap-and-prompt_command-in-bash/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works, but feels a bit kludgy (I'm hoping for a more clever answer):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='at_prompt=t'
trap '
    [ -z "${at_prompt+set}" ] ||
    printf %s\\n "most recent history line: $(history 1)" >&2
    unset at_prompt
' DEBUG
```

Comment: Note that the debug trap is triggered for every command in `PROMPT_COMMAND` as well, so be careful when adding more commands to `PROMPT_COMMAND`.